# solr: Boosting documents that match all terms

Tags: solr

I would like to have documents that match all terms rank the highest, followed by the partial matches. Among the full matches and among the partial matches, the documents should be ranked by default behavior (IF-TDF). I figured (correct me if I'm wrong) that the best way to do this would be with boost queries, but I am not sure what the correct syntax is.

Here are some of my handler settings:

```
  <str name="defType">edismax</str>
  <str name="qf">parent_and_self_description details^0.0001 info^0.0001 code^10000</str>
```

And let's say an example query is `q=cheese apple`

How should I set my bq? I guessed something like `bq=(cheese AND apple)^100` or `bq=(+cheese +apple)^100` but obviously this is not working so it must be syntactically wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't just a regular query do that for you? Another option is to apply multiple boost queries, `bq=field:cheese&bq=field:apple`

Comment: No sometimes partial matching docs with high term frequency will out-score another doc that is a full match. Multiple boost queries would boost partial matches as well. I solved the problem by applying phrase fields boosts with a large phrase slop, I'm not sure if that's the best way though.

Comment: You could use a field with disabled term frequencies, so that the tf doesn't affect score - just that it is present. `omitTermFreqAndPositions` for the field will do this (and disable positions, so you wouldn't be able to use that field for phrase matches in that case). However your solution seems OK, but if you run into performance problems I'd try the simpler solution. You could possibly run into a situation where the idf will affect the score too much (I don't remember if idf is still calculated across the whole index for a single term, but I believe that's the case).

Comment: A custom similarity that returns 1/1 for tf and idf could be a solution in that case.

Comment: Thank you! I do want the TF-IDF to rank the documents, and I am not familiar with similarity but I will definitely look into it if I run into performance issues as you said.